# Load pretrained pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

Haven't been able to find this solution elsewhere though the question may seem really simple.

I have a pytorch (.pt) file and I'm trying to load it. I know that I need to construct the model  first by doing

```
model = MyModel()
```

but my pytorch file buiilds a model (se_resnext101_32x4d) that I did not make a class for. As such when I try and do

```
model = se_resnext101_32x4d()
```

I get an error

```
name 'se_resnext101_32x4d' is not defined
```

I've tried doing

```
import pretrainedmodels

model = pretrainedmodels.__dict__[se_resnext101_32x4d]()
```

but the error persists.

Comment: did you try:  from your_file_name import se_resnext101_32x4d()

Comment: Your `.pt` file only contains the models state (the parameters) not the model structure i.e. the forward definition. You can't initialize an `nn.Module` just with its state if that's what you're asking. Where are you getting this `.pt` file from?

Answer (score 0):

After a little search, it appears you are trying to use [this package](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch) which contains pretrained models and an API to download and use them. According to [their documentation](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch/blob/master/README.md) you can load a model like so:

```
import pretrainedmodels

Model = pretrainedmodels.__dict__['se_resnext101_32x4d']
model = Model(num_classes=1000, pretrained='imagenet')
model.eval()
```

Don't forget to install the *pip* package if you haven't already:

```
pip install pretrainedmodels
```